# How to exclude series from pie-chart if there are a few of them (Highcharts.js)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please help me out - what should I do in order to hide one particular segment of one particular chart (Also I want the rest of pie to fit vacated space with animation) ?

Here is the code where I have 2 pies with different sets of data: http://jsfiddle.net/andreypoznyak/PhjQh/3/

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: null,
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        center: ["25%", "50%"]
    },{
        data: [{
            color: "red",
            y: 10,
            name: "a"
        }, {
            color: "yellow",
            y: 20,
            name: "b"
        }, {
            color: "green",
            y: 25,
            name: "c"
        }],
        center: ["75%", "50%"]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use visible paramter for point (one slice) 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible

http://jsfiddle.net/PhjQh/4/

```
{
            color: "red",
            y: 10,
            visible:false,
            name: "a"
        }
```

Comment: I assume that I'll have to reset series for all pies on chart in this case and it will cause redrawing for all of them. I just need to redraw one particular pie

Comment: So you need to two charts in two divs separately, not as two series.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it would be better